# What's the age of account in Islam?

Tags: age

My 16 year old brother passed away recently. Would he be viewed as a child in the grave or tried as an adult?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether your brother reached the age of puberty or not, as well as whether he was sane and responsible for his actions or not.
If he has not reached puberty, there are different schools of thought about the maximum age, such as 15 years according to the Shafis and Hanbalis or 18 years according to the Hanafis and Malikis.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is much appreciated :)

Comment: For hanafi's I believe it’s determined that a person is mature from the moment they get a wet dream however if they don’t have a wet dream then it’s from the age of 15 according to shariah I believe (for males)